# I want to export computer data using Get-CimInstance to a csv but also include the computer name

Tags: powershell, scripting

Right now I'm running

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $i.DNSHostName -Class CIM_Processor | Select-Object "Name", "NumberOfCores" | Export-Csv -Path .\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append`
```

This will put the CPU name and core count in a CSV fine but how can I add in the hostname as another column?

Comment: Try `Select-Object "Name", "NumberOfCores", "PSComputerName"`

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen I think that works fine but I'm also curious about how I could combine different cmdlet results into one row? Like if I get the cpu name and cores of a computer in one cmd then get say network info in another and want that all as one csv record how would I combine objects like that?

Comment: That's a separate question. You could still use `Select-Object`, but would need to use a [Calculated Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for using a PsCustomObject, which allows you to dynamically create an object with arbitrary properties/values.

```
$cimProcessor = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $hostName -Class CIM_Processor

$row = [PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName = $hostName
    Name = $cimProcessor.Name
    NumberOfCores = $cimProcessor.NumberOfCores
}

$row | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you want to retrieve information from a remote machine first, then you can skip the calculated property and simply select the `PSComputerName` property instead:

> **Note:** The ellipses `...` indicate the code before or after from your original sample.

```
... | Select-Object PSComputerName, Name, NumberOfCores | ...
```

Any cmdlet which connects to remote systems via WinRM should have this property automatically set when data is returned over a remote session.

---

If you are running this from a local session, you could use `Select-Object` to create a calculated property, then call the `hostname` command to populate its value:

```
... | Select-Object "Name", "NumberOfCores", @{
  Name = 'ComputerName';
  Expression = { hostname };
} | ...
```

This solution is often suitable for cross platform scripts since a `hostname` binary is available out of the box on Windows, MacOS, and most major distributions of Linux.

---

#### Explaining Calculated Properties

Calculated properties work by defining a hashtable in a specific format and providing the hashtable as a property to be computed just as you would use a string for a real property on the object:

```
$property = @{
  Name = 'PropertyName';
  Expression = { 'ScriptBlock' };
}

# Note that the hashtable can be specified inline as shown above
# or as a variable like shown here
[PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'Bender'; Loves = 'Bending' } |
  Select-Object Name, Loves, $property
```

Keep in mind that within the Expression `ScriptBlock`, `$PSItem`/`$_` is set to the current object in the pipeline. Use this to reference static or instance properties from the current object you are selecting information from.